# Meteor, logging in with Facebook but accessing profile

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Please advise as the best way to handle the following situation:

I created a custom sign-up form with:

1. Firstname
2. Lastname
3. Email
4. Password
5. More

These are stored in the "Profile" array in the user account document.

I just tied in Facebook login to my app and it worked, however it stores things differently than I initially setup. I'm using handlebars helpers to display a users firstname, but Facebook info is stored as "name: full name"

What's the best way to deal with this?

So when a user creates an account using the meteor password system:

```
{{currentUser.profile.firstname}} <- works
```

But if they use Facebook it does not, becaues it's stored in "name" instead of firstname.

Just some ideas or best practices needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Accounts.onCreateUser()` callback on the server to normalize the user document before it's saved in the database.

http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: Thank you! What would be the proper method to return the newly created user's ID? For example, I'd like to use the sendVerificationEmail function.

Comment: @user1447679 The email is sent automatically after the `validateNewUser()` callback is successful, assuming you set the configuration to do so. http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm only using accounts-base and accounts-password though. Would that be the reason? I'm using all custom forms and validation for login and registration. I was able to pull the userId from local storage of the current signed in user to send the email verification though.

Comment: So in other words, I'm having to call the sendVerificationEmail function manually.